# Router needs to support SNMP?

Tags: router, snmp

I want to monitor a couple of servers using SNMP. I connect using an industrial router. But this router doesn't seem to support SNMP. Could this become a problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your router may not support using SNMP to monitor it, but I can assure you it will support SNMP in the sense of passing through data.

SNMP sits in the Application Layer - your router doesn't care about that, only Layer 3 stuff.